# Context for Android MediaPlayer in React NativeModule

Tags: android, react-native, media-player

I've got the basics of a Native Module working (from the docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) and am attempting to cause the module to trigger audio using the android.media.MediaPlayer (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer)

I'm not seeing any error, but I'm not hearing any audio yet. I think my problem may be with "context", I am unclear on how to get that in this situation, to use in this line:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
```

I believe I would need to use android context rather than the ReactApplicationContext, but not sure about the proper way to get it. Thanks for any help here!

```
package com.nativemoduletest;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.util.Log;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;


public class CalendarModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    CalendarModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "CalendarModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void createCalendarEvent(String name, String location) {
        Log.d("CalendarModule", "Create event called with name: " + name
                + " and location: " + location);

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.context, R.raw.piano1_c4); // where do you get the context?
        mediaPlayer.start(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android application context is callable from the ReactApplicationContext, as shown here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3895

In the above code, use:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.context.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.piano1_c4);
```